# Register-ScheduledTask: The parameter is incorrect. WHICH ONE?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-4.0, windows-server-2012-r2

What am I doing here? I keep getting `Register-ScheduledTask: The parameter is incorrect.` I tried different combinations but same problem! I'm running ***PowerShell 4*** on WinServer2012 and as System. This runs fine on PS7 and PS5.

```
        $taskname = "anyname"
        $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $sysprepCommand -Argument $sysprepParameters
        $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -RunLevel Highest -UserId SYSTEM
        New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Principal $principal | Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskname -Force | Start-ScheduledTask | Unregister-ScheduledTask -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Is this the complete error message you get? If not - please share the complete error message - formatted as code as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds liek the cmdlet cvhanged from PS4 onwards - just type `help Register-ScheduledTask -Detailed` to see what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `-Principal $principal` is correct and fine. However, for 2012er Systems you need to add `-LogonType ServiceAccount` in case you want to use a ServiceAccount instead of a UserAccount.

Example from my environment (tested on WinSvr 2012 - 2022):

```
$ComputerName = $env:Computername

$Action1 = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "msiexec.exe" -Argument "/I AzureConnectedMachineAgent.msi /l*v $($ComputerName)_azcmagent_update.log /qn"
$Action2 = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'azcmagent'"
$actions = @($Action1, $Action2)

$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -WeeksInterval 4 -DaysOfWeek "Saturday" -At 10AM
$taskPrincipal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest

$ScheduledTask = New-ScheduledTask -Action $actions -Trigger $trigger -Description $TaskDescription -Principal $taskPrincipal

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -InputObject $ScheduledTask
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the cmdlet changed but the docs don't say so. Here's what I ended up doing.

It seems like `-Principal $principal` existing in the task was not recognized by `Register-ScheduledTask`. Note that `Register-ScheduledTask` can accept a `-TaskName`. Just not a task that has `-Principal`.

```
$taskname = "myTask"
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $myCommands -Argument $myArgs
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskname -Action $action -RunLevel 'Highest' -User 'SYSTEM' -Force | Start-ScheduledTask | Unregister-ScheduledTask -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with job name,my job name had a ':' ..

```
Example:
$jobname ='test: job'
```

Fix is to remove `:`